Tall married girl attacked in her home
I don't know what year this came out but I think it was recent. 
There was a tall girl kinda dark skinned but kinda not. She had a husband in the beginning and then people came and robbed her house and shot him and a good person came in and rescued her and she didn't want to be rescued but 2 people who rescued her had to fight off the robbers. The tall girl brought a huge suitcase with shoes that were made of diamonds and gold and I don't remember much besides they had to get the girl to LA.

I believe you could be talking about "Hot Pursuit". The tall girl would be Sofía Vergara.
And the initial scene description appears to match:

Rose Cooper is a San Antonio Police Department officer whose work ethic has made her too intense in her personal life. While out on a date, she scares the guy away after she defensively pulls a gun on him. She chases him down just to give him back his wallet.
At the station, Cooper is brought in to meet Detective Jackson. Captain Emmett informs Cooper that she will escort Jackson to protect a cartel informant named Felipe Riva and his wife Daniella after Felipe decides to testify against notorious cartel leader Vincente Cortez. This is Cooper's first job back in the field after her last incident where she saw the mayor's son yell "Shotgun!" while out with his friends, leading Cooper to tase him in a spot where he spilled alcohol and causing him to catch fire. Cooper's name has become a verb synonymous with screw-ups, and she's found a chance to redeem herself.
Cooper and Jackson arrive at the Riva home, where Daniella is angry at her husband for making them targets. Cooper finds her packing a bunch of materials with her. Downstairs, gunshots start to ring out. Two masked men shoot at Jackson and Felipe. The two of them are shot and killed. Cooper runs to the garage to find Daniella hiding in the backseat of a car. Cooper turns the car on and drives away from the scene. She breaks the news of Felipe's death to Daniella, making her wail hysterically. She tries to call for help, but Cooper makes her drop the phone on the road. Cooper pulls the car over, and Daniella grabs her bag to walk away on her own. Cooper handcuffs herself to Daniella to make sure she's close to her. Then a truck plows into the car, spraying a ton of hidden cocaine everywhere. Cooper gets jacked up on coke and gets the truck driver to drive them to a nearby store to get new clothes.

Trailer here:



